# Inclusion of more than two JQuery libraries creates problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am including these JQuery libraries:

```
src="JQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"
src="JQuery/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js
src="JQuery/menu_login.js"
src="GjQuery/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"
src="GjQuery/jquery-ui-personalized-1.6rc2.min.js
src="GjQuery/jquery.flickr-1.0.js"
"GjQuery/jquery.flickrGallery-1.0.2.js"
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$().ready(function(){
$('#Gallery').flickrGallery({
    galleryHeight: 450
});
});
</script>
```

In this code, I am including 3 JQuery libraries in my Web application. I have two queries in my Web application before it's working fine, but when I have added the flickr library, it's doing problem. Problem is that as I include flickr library, the other two stop working. If I change the order of the inclusion then flickr library stops wroking or from other two one not doing work.  Any idea?

Comment: What are you three libraries (and versions) and what version of jquery are you using?  We need some more info...

Comment: And for the love of whichever deity you prefer, let spell check into your life.

Comment: @ true u got the versions ???

Comment: In your question you say 3 libraries (*jqueries*) but you list 6...  and I agree with coreyward (+1) - you need to accept some answers, you've asked 11 questions and none are accepted...

Comment: @Haseeb You're loading two different versions of both jQuery and jQuery UI. At some point here you need to quit copying and pasting and start learning how these things go together.

Comment: i have broke them into 6 just for understanding ....i am just new to stack .. so i dont to how to do dat .. well if u cant help me .. no problm thanx ....

Comment: Guys/gals/pseudonyms, make answers into answers (below).

Comment: @D_N There aren't any answers here, just comments. (*blink. blink.*)

Comment: @coreyward, I guess I mistook the implicit 'you can't do that'/'stop that' in your comment as an answer. Instead of just verbal venting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the purpose behind including multiple versions of jQuery?

If you can, use only 1 (newest hopefully) version.

Alternatively, if each plugin you are using requires a different version, use NoConflict and make sure each plugin gets the correct version that it needs. You can also use closures and self invoking functions to still use $ like normal, while controlling which version you're using.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<!-- other scripts that depend on 1.4.2 --->
<script>
var $.1.4.2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<!-- other scripts that depend on 1.2.6 --->
<script>
var $.1.2.6 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script>
(function($){  
  // $ in here is jQuery 1.4.2 
})($.1.4.2);

(function($){
  // $ in here is jQuery 1.2.6 
})($.1.2.6);
</script>
```