# script files clashing with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, scrollbar, accordion

I am using custom scroll and accordion in a page but when I put both plugin's script in the page thn either one of tat is not working. I tried to merge both but still it is not working.

Here is my script for each plugin

**For custom scroll**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();   
             $('#maintab').tabs();              
        });
    </script>
```

For accordion

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/accordion.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery().ready(function(){  
    // applying the settings
    jQuery('.theMenu').Accordion({
        active: 'h3.selected',
        header: 'h3.head',
        alwaysOpen: false,
        animated: true,
        showSpeed: 400,
        hideSpeed: 800
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe because they are minified and some functions may interfere with each other, having the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 Jquery Libraries. Use Only one (the latest one) at the top of all scripts so your code should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/accordion.js"></script>
```

or see this post: [Inclusion of more than two jquery libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049220/inclusion-of-more-than-two-jquery-libraries-creates-problems)

Extracted from above post:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<!-- other scripts that depend on 1.7.2 --->
<script>
    var $.1.7.2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<!-- other scripts that depend on 1.2.6 --->
<script>
    var $.1.2.6 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using `. If we need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, we can return control of $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict():

See Also: [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: I tried adding only one library file but still it doesnt work

Comment: I used another accordion which is working fine now. but one question, how do we use the same accordion 2 times in single page? If it has id thn i cant, if i change it to class thn both r behaving similarly. Do u have any other plugin which work for multiple accorfion in same page

Comment: You can do it by initiating accordion function (having different id's) multiple time like `jQuery('#id1').Accordion({})` and `jQuery('#id2').Accordion({})` and so on...

Comment: var nestedAccordion=new TINY.accordion.slider("nestedAccordion");
nestedAccordion.init("nested","h3",1,-1,"acc-selected");
this is the code am using for accordion. How can I make multiple accordion with this code

Comment: one last question :) above sample is nice but how to close all the tabs by default? not the frst tab is opened by default in that code

Comment: One more question pls. How do  close the tab when I click on the same second time? Presently it is closing the tab when another tab is clicked

Comment: You can find the list of options (to be used in accordion) here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Accordion#options

Comment: How to add a class to active tab dynamically in script? I know I am kind of irritating but pls

Comment: yes but am not able to change the active css. http://jsfiddle.net/MX4xA/26/ Pls chk this

Comment: use the classes `.ui-state-active` as i used in my demo for your custom styles.